# If $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then for all $j \,\, \exists N_j$ such that for $n,m > N_j$ we have $|x_n -x_m| < 2^{-j}$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

My uncertainty lies within the following context, from lecture notes

[image: Problem]

I think it is a pretty bold claim and I am unsure how to derive it. I am grateful if anyone here has a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Cauchy sequence is this result but changing the $2^{-j}$ with any arbitrary $\epsilon$. Just take $\epsilon = 2^{-j}$ and you are done

Comment: Wow, I have the definition in front of me. How could I miss that. Thank you for your answer, probably saved me 20 minutes

Comment: No problem, happens to all, have a nice day